# can you explain free and shared levels of azure?

Tags: azure

I have a trial for `azure` that ends in a few days and an `aspx` application without database, this page has a misserable 50 requests/month and I would like to know :

**1. Can I host it in a free or shared level (after the trial expired)?**

**2. In the free level it says 0 Gb, but I suppose I will need more than 0 Gb, don't?**

**3. I suppose I need to buy something to use the free or shared levels, can you explain it?**

Comment: Were you happy with either answer Luis?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the free level without problems.

Looking at the latest prices:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/websites/

The free level allows you to have up to 1GB of storage and a 165MB daily bandwith, which seems more than enough.

Upgrading to Shared will allow you unlimited bandwith, more websockets and a custom DNS support. If you don't require any of that it should be ok with the Free level.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft could indeed make this information clearer. What you need to do is look at the costs for a Pay As You Go plan to find what you get for free.

You can host up to 10 apps with 1GB of disk space for free: 
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/app-service/

and the first 5GB of serviced requests are also free if you're using '[App Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/calculator/?scenario=appservice)' or '[Cloud Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/calculator/?scenario=cloud)'